# Why am I unable to deploy Ethereum Consortium Leader solution template to Azure?

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum

When I try to run the Ethereum Consortium Leader solution template in Azure it keeps failing when trying to deploy `vmExtensionLinkedTemplate`.

It looks like the specific operation that is failing has the status as `Conflict` with the following status message:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'newuserscript'. Error message: \"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=1\"."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: well, i don't think that anybody will be able to help you unless you show the whole template. also, wth is `vmExtensionLinkedTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying again today for maybe the 5th time it worked for me, I guess it might have been a problem with Azure since other people had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue since yesterday. I am simply following azure marketplace template "Ethereum Consortium Leader" and putting in necessary values.